# WhatsApp—How to prevent notifications from returning after swiping them away?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

When I get a new message in WhatsApp, I get a notification that contains the beginning of the message. After I swipe it away, the old message always returns when I get a new message. How can I prevent those zombie messages from coming back? There is a "mark as read" feature but that is too complicated to use, I have to swipe down and then click, I just want one swipe to completely clear the notification.

Answer (score 0):

The notifications are showed by the Whatsapp (and there is no option in whatsapp to change this). You'll have to request Whatsapp dev for this feature.
Personally, I don't think they will consider your request so easily. 
Anyways, Good Luck!